# Author name disambiguation data

Tags: database, author, pubmed, disambiguation

I'm doing a research on the author name disambiguation problem. I want to make some experiments. I want to cluster citation records. I need training data and testing data in which the true author of each publication record is available. There  are many bibliographic databases like DBLP, Medline and Pubmed etc. I'm confused about the testing phase. Is it a good practice to divide the DBLP into training and testing? Are DBLP citation records manually added? Can I guarantee that each citation record is assigned to the true author in DBLP? Is there any suggestion for training and testing databases. 
Note: In the literature I noticed that in some paper they used Pubmed for training and DBLP for testing although the first one is for medical publications and the second for computer.

Comment: "Can I guarantee that each citation record is assigned to the true author in DBLP?" Please be aware that although DBLP is manually curated, this is in no way a guarantee of DBLP being free of errors. The sources of metadata errors are manifold, and often even manual research cannot uncover "the truth". DBLP may be of higher quality and less prone to errors than other aggregated data sources because of its unique approach to data curation. But with a bit of experience you can easily find a lot of examples where even DBLP got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my take on your questions:

**I'm confused about the testing phase. Is it a good practice to divide the DBLP into training and testing?**

The practice used is to split the data for training and testing. However it'll be a good idea to insure that there exist training samples for each testing sample.

**Are DBLP citation records manually added? Can I guarantee that each citation record is assigned to the true author in DBLP?**

According to this paper, DBLP citations records are manually added.
https://clgiles.ist.psu.edu/papers/ECDL-2005-Citation-Databases.pdf

**Is there any suggestion for training and testing databases.**

ANDDataset1 has been used in some work for such tasks 
https://sites.google.com/site/tinhuynhuit/dataset

You can also try KDD Cup 2013 - Author Disambiguation Challenge
https://www.kaggle.com/c/kdd-cup-2013-author-disambiguation/data